# spring validation with @valid where/how custom error messages

Tags: spring, validation, hibernate-validator

I'm trying to do some spring validation with the error messages in properties files.
But the examples I find all seem to have the values hardcoded, or gotten from a properties file but using a validator class and retrieving it there.

My setup is a bit different.
I'm using the @Valid annotation in my requestmapping, and my @Valid class uses @NotNull etc.
I've seen some examples where people do @NotNull(message = "blablabla");
But that's also hardcoded, and I'd like to put the messages in a properties file so I can easily edit it on the fly and so I can easily implement i18n in the future.

Any input on how to achieve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works exactly the same way as with explicit `Validator` - you [declare a `MessageSource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-messagesource) and write error messages in `.properties` files. Messages codes are formed as `constraintName.modelAttributeName.propertyName`:

```
publib class Foo {
    @NotNull private String name;
    ...
}
```

.

```
@RequestMapping
public String submitFoo(@Valid Foo foo, ...) { ... }
```

`messages.properties`:

```
NotNull.foo.name=...
```

`MessageSource` declaration:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value = "messages" />
</bean>
```