# How to internationalize spring-mvc form error messages?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, internationalization

I want to translate the default error messages for form validation, for example, when I annotate a field as **@NotEmpty**, I should receive an error like:

```
may not be empty
```

when I left the field empty. Now I want this message in other languages, so what should I do in order to translate them? I want this to work with every field annotated with **@NotEmpty**, and also for other messages...

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [spring validation with @valid where/how custom error messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281165/spring-validation-with-valid-where-how-custom-error-messages)

Comment: Hmmm, there they suggest to declare something like "NotEmpty.class.attribute", but I need something more generic, in order to display the same message to all attributes in every class that are annotated with @NotEmpty. Something like "NotEmpty.*.*" =P

Comment: Solved, in my messages.properties I put "NotEmpty=Required", and is applied to every field annotated with @NotEmpty, thanks @axtavt!

Answer (score 0):

Spring can hook up into your internationalized error codes I think ...

My validator class extends Validator and implements setting a MessageSource and then can pass in errorCode like below and Im guessing it autolooks it up via the MessageSource set (which i set via a Spring Bean):

```
public static void rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(Errors errors,
                                             String field,
                                             String errorCode,
                                             String defaultMessage)
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/ValidationUtils.html#rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace-org.springframework.validation.Errors-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Here is a pretty close example to what I have (minus they use LocaleResolver):
http://vardhan-java2java.blogspot.com/2010/08/spring-internationalization-i18n.html

Answer (score -2):

You can add custom messages to @NotEmpty by using it like this:

```
@NotEmpty( message = "Your error message")
```

Comment: the question was not about message customization, but internationalization