# Internationalization off validation errors using @Valid

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, internationalization

I cannot get internationalization to work for validation errors using the @Valid annotation.

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

<html> 
<body>
<form:form  action="processentry.do" method="post" commandName="entryForm">
<TABLE >
    <TBODY>
        <TR>
            <TD><spring:message code="messages.name" text="Name" /></TD>
            <TD><INPUT type="text" name="name" value="${ entryForm.name }" size="20"></TD>
            <td><font color="red"><form:errors path="name" /></font></td>           
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD></TD>
            <TD><INPUT type="submit" value="Submit"></TD>
        </TR>
    </TBODY>
</TABLE>
<br />
Current Locale : ${pageContext.response.locale}
</form:form>
</body>
```

My Form

```
public class EntryForm {
    @NotEmpty("required")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 20)
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }   
}
```

The controller:

```
@Controller
public class EntryController {

    @RequestMapping(value ="/processentry.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public String entry(@Valid EntryForm entryForm, BindingResult result, Map model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "entry.jsp";
        }
            model.put("entryForm", entryForm);
            return "showresult.jsp";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value ="/entry.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String entry(Map model){
        EntryForm entryForm = new EntryForm();
        model.put("entryForm", entryForm);
      return "entry.jsp";
    }
}
```

The spring configuration file:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven /> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="controllers" />

    <!-- Register the messages.properties -->
    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="resources.messages" />
    </bean>
```

I support 2 languages: english and dutch:

messages_en.properties:

```
messages.name = Name
```

messages_nl.properties:

```
messages.name = Naam
```

I also want dutch error messages during a validation error. 
I tried adding the message in the properties file, but that does not work.

messages_nl.properties:

```
messages.name = Naam

javax.validation.constraints.Size.message=lengte moet tussen {min} en {max} zijn
org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty.message=mag niet leeg zijn
```

My question is, how can I show my own messages for validation errors?

Comment: Perhaps spring is unable to resolve your locale. This is expected to be done as documented in this [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-localeresolver).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281165/spring-validation-with-valid-where-how-custom-error-messages

you should check this thread!